# obtener IP de la maquina en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas estoy queriendo obtener el ip de la maquina .

para eso estoy realizando este codigo que cuando lo ejecuto desde mi web y lo publico en mi IIS local funciona y me obtiene mi IP de mi maquina.

```
   IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

 String IP = Convert.ToString(localIPs[1]);
```

Esta la url de mi pagina que al momento de calcular se debe obtener el ip de la maquina que esta haciendo la prueba.

pero al momento que lo publico en una web externa es decir que se ingresa en internet.

veo que se obtiene el IP del IIS y no el IP del usuario.

espero que me puedan ayudar.

/******************  Rspta de Luciano Montañez ******************************/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Coloque este codigo.

```
String IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: El servidor no puede obtener el IP del cliente, es el cliente el que tiene (si quiere) que darle el IP al servidor

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz entiendo , entonces no se puede obtener el ip del cliente ya que solo quiero saber que al momento que rellenen mi formulario yo pueda saber de donde o quien lo esta ingresando. como metodo de seguimiento.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz edite mi pregunta.

Comment: "::1" Es para localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro de un controller, cuando recibes una request.-
Esto viene dentro del objeto `HttpContext.Request`

```
string IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Nota : El hecho de obtener `"::1"` como respuesta, no es un error, sino que esto lo devuelven mientras haces `request/response` desde el mismo `localhost`

Comment: no es mvc es asp.net webform pero me imagino que debe funcionar probare. Gracias.

Comment: Montañes lo coloque en mi codigo y salio esa numero lo que adjunte en mi pregunta. no me obtiene el IP.

Comment: Puedes mostrar HttpContext.Current   completo ?

Comment: Montañes ya coloque

Comment: "::1" No es un error, solo que muestra porque estas conectado desde localhost

Comment: es decir si lo publico en la web si me deberia obtener el IP ?

Comment: Claro, mientras accedas a una maquina diferente de la del localhost.

Comment: Montañes me funciono gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());// objeto para guardar la ip
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();// esta es nuestra ip
                }
            }
```

Comment: saludos, gracias por apoyar pero las respuestas que son solo código sin explicación alguna generalmente son marcadas como de baja calidad; te recomiendo leer [answer] y tratar de mejorar tu aporte